# Is there a field limit that can be saved in an Export Members function

Tags: civimember, export

CiviCRM 4.7.0 and WP 4.4.1 - When doing an Export Members, selecting fields for export and selecting "Use Save Field Mapping" it won't save... unless we limit the number of fields.  Can someone give me the limit on this please.  THANKS.